# mailto not opening email form

Tags: html, mailto

I want to open email that fills the following details. I am using chrome. But the email is not opening. I have to press send only and then the email should be sent. Is there any way like this.
**Code**

```
   <a href="mailto:coolfire525@gmail.com?cc=coolfire525%40gmail.com&bcc=coolfire525%40gmail.com&body=Dear%20Global%20Supply%20Chain%20Group%0A%20%0AI%20would%20like%20you%20to%20send%20me%20your%20report%20titled%20A%20FIDUCIARY%20BOARD%20REPORT%20-%20%20THE%20FUTURE%20OF%20BUSINESS%20IN%20THE%20AGE%20OF%20B2B%20NETWORKS%2C%20and%20attach%20an%20invoice%20for%20the%20report.%20I%20understand%20that%20I%20can%20ask%20for%20a%20refund%20and%20return%20the%20report%20in%20original%20condition%20within%2030%20days%2C%20if%20I%20do%20not%20like%20the%20content.">Mail Now</a>
```

Comment: why is this flagged for PHP?

Comment: to grab full stack developers attention too. Or if there is any solution for this in php @Forbs

Comment: Do you have a email client configured on your computer?

Comment: no i don't think so. how could i check that @fubar

Answer (score 0):

It about how your default mail application setup on your computer...

it's worked for me.

Also see this link for more info: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/Getting-Gmail-to-handle-all-mailto-links-with-registerProtocolHandler

Comment: how can i check that default mail application.

Comment: if there are many clients and they use different types of email application then what in that case. Is there any way that it should open directly the default mail . @Moshe

Comment: @WaqasAamer That's exactly what is happening now. the link will open the default email application on client computer. You probably do not have the right definition - just for you. If you want to send mails without client errors use server side language like php to send the mail.